# Insert into mysql with prepared statment - not working

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am using php-login.net projectfiles for a tiny webapp. I just tried to connect to m db and insert some stuff but am keep getting this strange error which i cannot figure out. What am missing in this code

```
$query = $db->prepare('INSERT INTO cours (category, title, description, places, price) VALUES (:category, :title, :description, :places, :price');
$query->execute(array(':category' => $category, ':title' => $title, ':decription' => $decription, ':places' => $places, ':price' => $price));
```

Comment: see that quote `:price');` <<< right there? wrong place and error checking would have told you that. along with a missing bracket. http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php - edit: and a  typo maybe even a few typos. Again... error checking. http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.error-handling.php

Comment: Start by reading the manual http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php and tutorials.

Answer (score 1):

You had a typo in `description` (was `decription`) also a `)` was missing after `:price`

```
$query = $db->prepare('INSERT INTO cours (category, title, description, places, price) VALUES (:category, :title, :description, :places, :price)');
$query->execute(array(':category' => $category, ':title' => $title, ':description' => $description, ':places' => $places, ':price' => $price));
```

Can you try now and tell us if it works?

Comment: oh you noticed it. wonder why. Question's off-topic btw. we also don't know if `$decription` is their actual variable.

Comment: Thanks @Fred-ii- for the `)` tip

Comment: Yes but the `:decription` part was wrong and by following the logic of the other variables, `$decription` could be too

Comment: Sure, no argument for the former. But, for the latter; that we don't know for certain because the guy didn't show it in the question. Maybe... just maybe. I didn't bother submitting an answer for this, and for a few reasons. One: it's off-topic as per what Stack's standards. Two: it's unclear. Good luck ;-)

Comment: I just submitted the answer because I can't coment :(

Comment: @AlanRezende Now you see why I didn't post an answer? The guy edited the question that is nowhere near the original post http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/33685056/1 - I'll upvote your answer because it answered the original post.

Comment: @Fred-ii- now I see that. I was just trying to help, since I'm new here I'm starting to get the flow now. Thanks for the tips!

Comment: @AlanRezende I know you did Alan and it's not your fault. You answered the original post. The OP needs to read up on PDO's prepared statements and I've posted a link under their answer along with a bonus comment ;-) Looks like you can start commenting now ;-) oh, and you're welcome Alan.